# Is it possible to convert Iterable with MapEntry type to Map type without looping?

Tags: flutter, performance, loops, dictionary, iterable

A newbie to Dart, who's trying to get into Flutter.
Is it possible to convert MapEntry to Map without looping, or shorter method/ better performance way to achieve the same result?

I have a returned type of Iterable, with MapEntry<String, int> like below.

```dart
final Map<String, int> laptopPricing = <String, int>{
  'MacM1': 120000,
  'RogFlowX13': 170000,
  'LenovoLegion': 110000
};

const int budgetOnHand = 150000;
final laptopWithinBudget = laptopPricing.entries.where((element) => element.value <= budgetOnHand); //filtering a map using entries's value

print(laptopWithinBudget); //prints (MapEntry(MacM1: 120000), MapEntry(LenovoLegion: 110000)) because the "where" method returns an Iterable MapEntry
```

What I would like to do, is to convert the Iterable with MapEntry, to a simple Map, with just Key and Value, without the "MapEntry" within the collection, and without using any sort of looping method for the conversion. (Just trying to learn and see if it is possible to achieve without using any loop, due to the concern of performance issue)
(Also, any best practice/ much better way to do it or advice such as "You shouldn't even use this if you're doing that", is more than welcome :D)

I have managed to achieve it with the map method (as far as I know, this is considered as looping, as it iterate through all the elements within a collection, but please correct me if I'm wrong on that)

```dart
final returnsMapUsingLooping = Map.fromIterables(
    laptopWithinBudget.map((e) => e.key),
    laptopWithinBudget.map((e) => e.value));

print(returnsMapUsingLooping); //prints {MacM1: 120000, LenovoLegion: 110000}
```

Appreciate all the help here, thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Map` class has a `fromEntries` named constructor which is exactly what you want here:

```
final asMap = Map<String, int>.fromEntries(laptopWithinBudget);
print(asMap);
```

Which yields `{MacM1: 120000, LenovoLegion: 110000}`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly the answer I was looking for. Due to my beginner repuation, I could only accept your answer, as the best answer, but can't really increase your vote, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have two way for this solution, try it:

```
final Map<String, int> laptopPricing = <String, int>{'MacM1': 120000, 'RogFlowX13': 170000, 'LenovoLegion': 110000};
final Map<String, int> laptopWithinBudget = <String, int>{};

const int budgetOnHand = 150000;
//first way
for (var element in laptopPricing.entries) {
  if (element.value <= budgetOnHand) {
    laptopWithinBudget.addAll({element.key: element.value});
  }
}
//second way (recommend)
laptopWithinBudget.addEntries(laptopPricing.entries.where((element) => element.value <= budgetOnHand));
print(laptopWithinBudget);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I seriously think this is also the best answer, but I couldn't accept both answers to a question...no idea why it has to work this way since there are many ways to solving a question...
In any case, thank you so much for sharing your wisdom. Your second way seems to be the most shortest way and simplest way to handle my situation.